# How to debug YAF with visual studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, express, visual-studio-debugging, yaf

I am building a membership provider for use with YAF. I want to be able to debug YAF to understand and follow the process through.

I downloaded and installed YAF sucessfully. I then installed the YAF sources and built them sucessfully.

So, I have a website under VS2010 express that works, and the new YAF binary DLLs from the build.

I cannot see how to "attach" the source files to enable debugging the website.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer (found somewhere on stackoverflow,lost where but thanks anyway):-

1. Just needed to add the project to the website solution
2. By default, the solution is not shown in the solution explorer window
3. To get the solution added to the soluton explorer:
       tools->Options -> Projects and Solutions 
       then check the "Always show solution" box

Then right click the solution in the solution explorer window to add the project.